How to perform rebuild link database from outside of sitecore server on a remote desktop
There is a way to rebuild the link database in Sitecore using the Control Panel available on Content Management. We are trying to automate this process of rebuilding the link database.
Now, I want to find a way to do this outside of the Sitecore server on a remote desktop, possibly through a Powershell script or Windows task scheduler.
I googled and found that this can be done through remoting setup on Sitecore. However, I am not finding a way to install the SPE Remoting PowerShell module on my local desktop. How can I do that?
How to do step 1 and step 2 of this document - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting

To perform the rebuild of the link database in Sitecore from a remote desktop, you can utilize the Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE) Remoting capabilities:
Step 1: Install the SPE Remoting Module on the Sitecore Server
Step 2: Install the SPE Remoting Module on Your Local Desktop
Download the SPE Remoting Module:
The SPE Remoting module should be part of the SPE package you downloaded earlier. Look for the Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions.Remoting.dll file within the package.
Install the SPE Remoting Module Locally:
Copy the Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions.Remoting.dll to a directory on your local machine (e.g., C:\Modules\Sitecore).
Open PowerShell on your local machine.
Import the module using the following command:
Import-Module "C:\Modules\Sitecore\Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions.Remoting.dll"
Step 3: Set Up Remoting and Script Execution
On your Sitecore server, enable remoting by running the following command in the Sitecore PowerShell Console:
Enable-ScriptSession -Name "Default" -UserName "admin" -Password "b" -SessionType Default -ConnectionUrl "https://your-sitecore-url" -AllowUntrustedCertificates
Create a Script to Rebuild the Link Database:
Start-Job {
    [Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseLinker]::RebuildDatabase('master')
}

Execute the Script Remotely from Your Local Desktop:
# Import the SPE Remoting Module
Import-Module "C:\Modules\Sitecore\Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions.Remoting.dll"

# Create a session to the Sitecore server
$session = New-ScriptSession -Name "SitecoreSession" -Url "https://your-sitecore-url" -UserName "admin" -Password "b" -AllowUntrustedCertificate

# Invoke the remote script to rebuild the link database
Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Start-Job {
        [Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseLinker]::RebuildDatabase('master')
    }
}

# Remove the session
Remove-ScriptSession -Session $session

Step 4: Automate Using Windows Task Scheduler
Set the program/script to powershell.exe and add the arguments to run your .ps1 script:
-File "C:\path\to\your\RebuildLinkDatabase.ps1"


You can download SPE and SPE Remoting module from the below location.
https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases
SPE module needs to be installed on the CM server and SPE Remoting needs to be extracted on your remote desktop.
In order to rebuild link database through remoting script, you need to run following powershell snippet from the remote desktop.
Import-Module -Name SPE

$session = New-ScriptSession -ConnectionUri "{{Sitecore_InstanceUrl}}" -Username {{Sitecore_AdminUsername}} -Password {{Sitecore_AdminPassword}}

$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
   "master", "web" | Get-Database | 
     ForEach-Object { 
          [Sitecore.Globals]::LinkDatabase.Rebuild($_)
     }
} -AsJob -Verbose

Wait-RemoteScriptSession -Session $session -Id $jobId -Delay 5 -Verbose

Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session

Note: In order for Import-Module -Name SPE command to execute, make sure you are opening Windows Powershell ISE from the folder location where you have extracted SPE Remoting module on the remote desktop.
You can watch following video for more details on setup.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGvT8eDdWrg
Update:
In have created blog that covers a step to step guide onto setting up SPE Remoting module, you can check that as well.
https://sitecorefoundation.in/2024/06/21/deep-dive-into-sitecore-powershell-remoting-module/
Hope this helps!!!
